# why can not I save some of SSIS packages

Tags: ssis

Some time While trying to save ssis packages .The save as window appears and it prompts "the .dtsx file already exist and want to replace or not?"

If i press yes it displays "The operation could not be completed".I am using a SSIS 2008 R2.Is it some kind of bug?
If not what is the solution?

Comment: Now It shows Exception of type 'system.outofmemoryException' was thrown

Comment: This is a frustrating error.The development machine has enough memory

Comment: Verify your machine and SQL Server installation are patched up to date. 2008R2 is currently at [SP1, CU7](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2703282) Also, when you start Task Manager, what does your Performance tab look like?